# Make a video "watch page"

Tags: php, mysql, html, html5-video

I am currently experimenting with HTML5 Video to see if it would be better than flash. The website I am building currently uses separate pages for each video (all the content is uploaded by me so an upload script is unnecessary) but I want to know how I would use PHP and MySQL to make a single "watch page". I would prefer this page to be standalone as I don't need anything else coded in PHP for now so the rest of my pages can use the extension .html

I can easily set up databases (server side, populating them is something im not too familiar with). I dont need a full website if ones already exist but finding the right wording for a google search is difficult (i keep finding PHP video tutorials).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Video Title - FTVO</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<h2>Video Title</h2>
<p>Watch this episode using the player below</p>
<h3>Getting a "Unsupported" error? Fix it by upgrading your browser. We recommend Firefox.</h3>
<a href="http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/"><img src="images/firefoxbanner.png"   alt="FirefoxBanner"/></a>
<br />
<video width="640" height="480" controls>
<source src="videos/e1.webm" type="video/webm">
Your Browser Doesn't Support this Element
</video>
<hr>
<p>This site is property of <b>TechXtra Web Services</b></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide the relevant code and more detail? Do you have a specific question / problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Do you already have a flash version in place? How are you populating it with the video you want to watch right now?

Comment: All im trying to do is use HTML5 and PHP together to make one page for all my content. For example: <video controls width="640" height="480"><source src="thefilechosenfromanotherpage" type="video/webm"> I also want this to work by having one page "myserver.com/video.php" playing all content not one page for each video like my current setup.

And no I am using pure HTML5 with webm videos.

Comment: Pass `thefilechosenfromanotherpage` to that page by e.g. a get parameter in some way (ID, name, plain path, etc.). Get the values you need from your DB (if any) and echo the URL in the place of `thefilechosenfromanotherpage`.

Comment: @AmazingDreams how would I send a parameter across pages. Im very new to PHP.

Comment: URL parameter: `http://www.yoursite.com/watchvideo.php?video=123`. The value `123` is now accessible with `$id = $_GET['video']`. Then `SELECT path FROM videos WHERE id=:id` and bind `$id` to `:id` using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). and `<source src="<?php echo $row['path']; ?>">`

Comment: I will have to read into PHP a bit more before I take this on then. Am I right in thinking this solution needs a database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're probably gonna need a database to make this work the way you want. Let's say your page is called [`example.com`](http://example.com), and there's a video in the address [`example.com/watch.php?video-id=123`](http://example.com/watch.php?video-id=123), what you'd want to do in your `watch.php` [PHP](http://www.php.net/) script is this:

First, retrieve the `video-id` [`GET`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.3) parameter

```
$videoId = $_GET['video-id'];
```

Then query your database for the information about the video (I highly recommend using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for this)

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
$sql = "
       SELECT id, title, src
       FROM videos
       WHERE id = $videoId
       LIMIT 1
";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$video = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

And *then*, displaying the corresponding HTML

```
<title><?= $video['title']; ?></title>

<source src="videos/<?= $video['src']; ?>" type="video/webm">

<!-- Whatever else you need to display -->
```

Comment: As posted by shashikant above, would this connect to my db: $connect = myqli_connect('localhost,'dbusername','dbpassword,'dbname'); (obviously changing server, username, password and db name)? Also would I be correct in saying that all the mysql stuff would need to be contained in <?php *script goes here* ?> ?

Comment: @JWassall I've updated my answer to show you how to create a connection with the database (changing the parameters, obviously). And not really, to access to the result from the query you'd just have to do `$video['<name of the column>']` in this case. If you want to show it in the HTML, use `<?php echo $video['<name of the column>'] ?>`.

Comment: I presume I need to use all the standard html stuff in the php page (<!DOCTYPE html> etc)? Also when linking to the video source in my database would I use `http://example.com/video/123.webm` (my mysql server is hosted separately as I use a webhosting company)

Comment: @JWassall Yes, you need all the other HTML elements (I just wrote the stuff where you insert the values from the query). I assumed that in your database you were storing the filepath of the videos, in a field called `video_src`, for example. That's what I'd do at least.

Comment: Im using 3 fields: id as a primary key, title for the title and src for the video source. I can do a screenshot of my phpmyadmin screen if that helps?

Comment: @JWassall I've updated the query so it matches your database. Is the table for your videos called `videos`?

Comment: Yes i wanted to keep it simple so `videos` seemed like a good idea.

Comment: I am now getting video now found, the video is definitely on the server and i am using firefox which worked with webm before.

Comment: @JWassall Replace `<source src="<?= $video['src']; ?>" type="video/webm">` for `<source src="videos/<?= $video['src']; ?>" type="video/webm">`. I forgot to add the `videos/` directory in my code.

Comment: I dont think that was the problem.. i failed to notice the `$videoId = $_GET['video-id']; $mysqli = new mysqli($mysql14.000webhost.com, $a1384884_user, $video1, $a1384884_videos); $sql = " SELECT id, title, src, pgtitle FROM videos WHERE id = $videoId LIMIT 1 "; $result = $mysqli->query($sql); $video = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC); mysqli_close($mysqli);` at the top of my page. I tried adding `<?php` and `?>` but it flagged up an error from my webhost.

Comment: Wait, perhaps you're not receiving the `video-id` GET parameter at all. Your address is something like `example.com/your_script.php?video-id=123`, right?

Comment: My address is `http://ftvo.webege.com/watch.php?video-id=1` and the first value in the database is 1 and the video file can be played by `http://ftvo.webege.com/videos/0001.webm` also here is the database config `http://ftvo.webege.com/images/database%201.png`

Comment: @JWassall I'd recommending looking at the source code of your page, and checking what's the `src` attribute of the `source` element. It would be informative to know what it says there.

Comment: I think I have diagnosed the problem. Using firefox's dev tools, i found that my webhost has modified the file to add an analytics code to the site and moved my php code to within html tags.. time to find a new host..

Comment: Yeah, perhaps that is what's causing the trouble :/

Comment: `http://ftvo.webege.com/images/hostproblems.png` thats the view from ff. I'll get back to you if i get problems again and I can prove its not the webhost.. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $videokey = $_REQUEST['key'];
  $connect = myqli_connect('localhost,'dbusername','dbpassword,'dbname');
  $SQL = "SELECT 'videoname' where videokey = $videokey ";
  $query = mysqli_query($SQL);
  $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>
<html>
<body>
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="<?php echo $result["videoname"];?>" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

i hope it will do the basic job of getting video from mysql table containing two coloumns named videokey and videoname.

Comment: Thats really helpful thanks. Could I have another column for videotitle so I could dynamically name the page in the head tag? Would <title><?php echo $result["videotitle"];?></title> work?

Answer (score 0):

I read your question and I think you want to make a single watch page with your all video. 
If stand alone player is having a playlist its may be ok. I suggest you can use some js library you 're not necessary to learn PHP and MYSQL. I found this Library

http://mediafront.org/osmplayer/#.Uf_wrzmy_Dc

I think its very easy to use. You can download it and then you can modify your code like this in your html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Video Title - FTVO</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<!-- Include the core jQuery and jQuery UI -->
<script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include the core media player JavaScript. -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="osmplayer/bin/osmplayer.compressed.js"></script>

<!-- Include the DarkHive ThemeRoller jQuery UI theme. -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="osmplayer/jquery-ui/dark-hive/jquery-ui.css">

<!-- Include the Default template CSS and JavaScript. -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="osmplayer/templates/default/css/osmplayer_default.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="osmplayer/templates/default/osmplayer.default.js">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#osmplayer").osmplayer({
            playlist: 'playlist.xml',
            width: '480px',
            height: '640px'
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Video Title</h2>
<p>Watch this episode using the player below</p>
<div id="osmplayer"></div>
<hr>
<p>This site is property of <b>TechXtra Web Services</b></p>
</body>
</html>
```

For playlist you create XML just change location path of video and image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <playlist version="1" xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/">
       <trackList>
          <track>
             <title>HTML5: Matagascar III</title>
             <location>http://progressive.totaleclips.com.edgesuite.net/105/e105598_257.mp4</location>
             <image>http://www.movieposter.com/posters/archive/main/143/MPW-71686</image>
          </track>
          <track>
             <title>HTML5: Snow White and the Huntsman</title>
                 <location>http://progressive.totaleclips.com.edgesuite.net/103/e103981_257.mp4</location>
             <image>http://www.movieposter.com/posters/archive/main/142/MPW-71148</image>
          </track>
          <track>
             <title>HTML5: Men in Black III</title>
             <location>http://progressive.totaleclips.com.edgesuite.net/105/e105857_257.mp4</location>
             <image>http://www.movieposter.com/posters/archive/main/146/MPW-73434</image>
          </track>
   </trackList>
</playlist>
```

Comment: I would prefer to use just HTML and PHP for this as I dislike javascript. Not that its difficult or anything but i want to try to use just HTML and PHP for as much as possible. This website is more of an educational project than anything else.

Comment: Ok I don't know you want to learn PHP then my answer is not solution at this situation. So sorry about that.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the method for youtube.com Video embed Php Code:
You can see URL Here `https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXX`. Here `XXX` you need to put this PHP code :

```php
<? php echo $_GET['id']; ? >
```

You should need to remove the space between `<?` and `php`from the start of the example `<? php` and at the end you only need to remove space between `?` and `>` . Write it like this: `?>`. Because it will not work if you keep space between them. When you do you can easily embed Youtube.com videos on your website or page. That's how you can create [PHP Pages for Youtube.com](http://prowrestling.pw/license/newy.php?id=bDidwMxir4o).